# Server suddenly throws out a fatal error, after dos attack

Tags: php

I have a script which i have been running on my server with no problems, and then today i am suddenly getting the following error, following a dos attack on the server. the server was rebooted and the offending ip address blocked but now this script isn't working.  I do think that in the process of trying to finding out what was wrong with the server that the apache module was re-installed so i wonder if this could be related to something there.

Fatal Error Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home/name/public_html/folder/ipology.class.phpon line 43

this is the section of code around line 43:

```
 function _fetch()
{
    if(!$sock = @fsockopen($this->_whois, $this->_port, &$errno, &$errstr, 10))
        return false;
    else
    {
        fputs($sock, "{$this->_ip}\n");
        while(!feof($sock))
            $buffer .= fgets($sock, 10240);
        fclose($sock);
        $this->_buffer = $buffer;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't know why its suddenly stopped working, or actually what the error relates to if anybody has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The dos attack automagically updated your php version. So it was probably a good thing. BTW the warning about it being deprecated has been there for PHP 5.3.0 (30 June 2009)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a new PHP-Version and you work in your example with references.

```
if(!$sock = @fsockopen($this->_whois, $this->_port, &$errno, &$errstr, 10))
```

remove the `&` before the `$errno` and `$errstr`.

```
if(!$sock = @fsockopen($this->_whois, $this->_port, $errno, $errstr, 10))
```

I think what you have seen in the PHP documentation is this

```
resource fsockopen ( string $hostname [, int $port = -1 [, int &$errno [, string &$errstr [, float $timeout = ini_get("default_socket_timeout") ]]]] )
```

this descripes the real implementation in C.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read in the PHP documentation, your version of PHP 5.4.0 will raise a fatal error when using "call-time pass-by-reference".

Here it says

> As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. **And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php